# How to delete element of an array in 68k assembly

Tags: assembly, motorola, 68000

I have an array of structures and I need to delete an element at a given position. Here are offsets for my structure.

```
MOVIE       equ  62
title       equ  0
year        equ  52
time        equ  54
rating      equ  56
```

Assuming I have an array of 12 elements, how would I delete element at position 5?

Comment: By copying everything above it one slot down.

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't care about order, just copy the last element there.

Comment: For the copy-everything-down method, you now have the same problem as `memmove`, so use an optimized `memmove` implementation.  Or use a level of indirection that lets you just delete from an array of pointers.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thanks, that helped!

Comment: The `rating` is six bytes, or am I mis-interpreting the first line?

Comment: @unwind it was a string with 5 characters (6 including null terminator). should've made it a bit more clear

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that you wouldn't have an 'array of structures'.
The ideal form is to have an array of *pointers* to structures, with each pointer referring to its own structure.

```
         MOVEQ   #5,D0       ;element you want to delete
         BSR     DEL_MOVE
         SIMHALT

DEL_MOVE
         LSL.W   #2,D0        ; long words
         LEA     MOVIES,A0    ; array start
         LEA     0(A0,D0),A2  ; element in array (starts at 0)
         LEA     11*4(A0),A1  ; end of array -1
DEL      MOVE.L  4(A2),(A2)+  ; move down
         CMP.L   A2,A1        ; at end yet?
         BLT.S   DEL          ; branch if not
         MOVE.L  #0,(A2)+     ; last element is null
         RTS


MOVIES   DC.L    MOVIE1, MOVIE2, MOVIE3 ...
MOVIE1   DS.B    62
MOVIE2   DS.B    62
         ...
```

Comment: Your present code will move garbage in the new top element! That is unless the longword at `4(A2)` was defined to contain a suitable pointer value (null or other).

Comment: Sorry, but this fix writes a null __behind__ the 12 longwords array! The `MOVE` that you wrote should become: `MOVE.L #0,-4(A2)`. This solves the issue regardless of the change from `LEA 12*4(A0),A1` to `LEA 11*4(A0),A1` which doesn't really do anything useful!

Comment: The problem exists if it is the last element that is to be deleted. The "move down" operation (that is redundant in this case) is done unconditionally and the null is written behind the array.

Comment: The simplest and even shortest solution is to keep your version 1 code, but to have the array defined with a terminating null-pointer. `MOVIES   DC.L    MOVIE1, MOVIE2, MOVIE3, ... ,MOVIE12, 0`.

Comment: An additional pitfall: Since the register `D0` was initialized and manipulated as a __word__ should then the `LEA 0(A0,D0),A2` instruction not become `LEA 0(A0,D0.W),A2`. I don't know if your assembler would use `.W` as a default!

Comment: If code size is of any importance, the instruction `MOVE.L  #0,(A2)+` wastes 4 bytes since `CLR.L (A2)` gets the job done with its opcode word only. Also why use the post-increment addressing mode at this point in the code?

Comment: No it doesn't write behind the array, since I also changed the reference to the last element down 4 bytes. 
I tend to avoid CLR out of habit as it is not as fast as MOVEQ when clearing registers, however you are right in thus instance.